# "Tiger read request doesn't belong to this archive (was 2, expected 11): >rq:?"

Tags: rise-of-the-tomb-raider

I'm getting this error after the first few seconds of a new game. My only option is "terminate". I tried loading another game and coming back but I'm still getting the error. What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a pre-loading issue. Wait for the game to 100% install itself to the console and try again.